# C++ does not name a type in Constructor definition

Tags: c++, constructor, compilation

I try to compile my code, I pretty sure I made a mistake in my headers or in the compilation but I don't understand where. I know that this is a basic problem, and I read some other topic, but I really don't understand. And I watch some other code I wrote and I don't see any difference...

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o out
```

I don't understand the error, so I also try :

```
g++ -c readFastqFile.cpp
```

**The error**

```
readFastqFile.cpp:8:1: error: ‘readFastq’ does not name a type
 readFastq::readFastq(){ //Constructor
```

And my files are :

**main.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    #include "readFastqFile.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    cout << "hello" <<endl;
    //readFastq allReads;
    return 0;
}
```

**readFastqFile.hpp**

```
#ifdef READFASTQFILE_HPP
#define READFASTQFILE_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class readFastq{
    public:
        readFastq(); //constructor

    private:
        string readName;
        string sequence;
        string score;
};
#endif // READFASTQFILE_HPP
```

**readFastqFile.cpp**

```
 #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
#include "readFastqFile.hpp"

using namespace std;

readFastq::readFastq(){ //Constructor
    readName = "bla";
    cout << readName <<endl;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo in your header guards `#ifdef` should be `#ifndef`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#ifdef READFASTQFILE_HPP` should be `#ifndef READFASTQFILE_HPP`. The `#ifdef` is causing the contents of readFastqFile.hpp to be ignored, so the class definition isn't being compiled.

See also [Include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard#Use_of_.23include_guards)

Comment: There's a "typo" close reason, you know.

Comment: @Puppy I don't consider this a typo, but a misunderstanding of include guards. Thanks for the downvote on a correct answer though.

Comment: @Puppy: That's no reason not to help the OP before it's closed, even if it won't be very helpful to others.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is. In addition, there's no evidence that he doesn't understand include guards.